# How to approach question like this? Integration on floor function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int _{e}^{{\pi}^2} \left \lfloor{\log_{\pi} (x)}\right \rfloor \mathrm dx$$ where [x] denotes greatest integer function equal to or less than x.

What I thought was to change the limit from e to $\pi$ and another as $\pi$ to ${\pi}^2$. But after writing like this I am not able to do anything further.

$$\int _{e}^{{\pi}} \left \lfloor{\log_{\pi} (x)}\right \rfloor \mathrm dx+\int _{\pi}^{{\pi}^2} \left \lfloor{\log_{\pi} (x)}\right \rfloor \mathrm dx$$

Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.
Note that for $x\in [\pi^n,\pi^{n+1})$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\lfloor \log_{\pi} x \rfloor=n $$
and $e\in [\pi^0,\pi^1)$.